# Should src be HTML-escaped in script tags in HTML?

Tags: html, html-entities, html-encode, html-escape-characters, script-tag

Given code like this:

```
<script src="http://example.com/?foo=1&amp;bar=2"></script>
```

Should the value of `src` be HTML-escaped as shown?

My experiments and research are showing ambiguous results.

Comment: thanks! turns out my experiment wasn't including a proper test as i thought it was. Your answer agrees with my findings now. (not sure why I was down voted — yes it's a very simple question but I couldn't find any other specific and conclusive discussion on SO or elsewhere).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. When you have doubts you can use the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org), which says `&` must be escaped into `&amp;` in this case.

Double-quotes attributes are parsed according to [this rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-%28double-quoted%29-state). When a `&` is found,

> Switch to the [character reference in attribute value state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-reference-in-attribute-value-state), with the [additional allowed character](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#additional-allowed-character) being U+0022 QUOTATION MARK (").

And the [Character reference in attribute value state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-reference-in-attribute-value-state) consists in

> Attempt to [consume a character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#consume-a-character-reference).
>
> If nothing is returned, append a U+0026 AMPERSAND character (&) to the
>   current attribute's value.
>
> Otherwise, append the returned character tokens to the current
>   attribute's value.
>
> Finally, switch back to the attribute value state that switched into
>   this state.

Therefore, it would (probably) work too if you didn't escape `&`. However, it will produce a parse error during the [consumption of the character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#consume-a-character-reference):

> If no match can be made, then no characters are consumed, and nothing
>   is returned. In this case, if the characters after the U+0026
>   AMPERSAND character (&) consist of a sequence of one or more
>   alphanumeric ASCII characters followed by a U+003B SEMICOLON character
>   (;), then this is a [parse error](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parse-error).

Note that you should escape it if you want to be safe:

> Certain points in the parsing algorithm are said to be [parse errors](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parse-error).
>   The error handling for parse errors is well-defined (that's the
>   processing rules described throughout this specification), but user
>   agents, while parsing an HTML document, may abort the parser at the
>   first parse error that they encounter for which they do not wish to
>   apply the rules described in this specification.